# AVAudioRecorder not resuming after AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

I used AVAudioRecorder to record audio. I added AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification to my viewcontroller to pause recording during interruption.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
   {      
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Other Stuffs
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(interrupted:)
                                             name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                           object:nil];
 }



-(void)interrupted:(NSNotification *) sender
   {
        if(recorder.isRecording)
          {
             // Code To Update UI
             [recorder pause];
          }
   }
```

Question 1: During interruption `interruped` method is called twice. Why?. During first call the recorder is nil. And during second call recoder.isRecording is NO. Why ?

Question 2: If application becomes action after receiving interruption, `[recorder record]` does not resume recording to file. But rather it starts to record it as new audio file.  How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Interrupted calls 2 times cause it notify you about begin interuption and about end. Look notification userInfo (your sender is notification object), it contains object for key `AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey`, which contains one of values: `AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan` or `AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded` . You can analyze it and deside when pause and when resume. But remember, second call is not necessary, it writed in documentation and it is true, i checked. System can deside when you can resume you work and when you don't need it.

About recorder there is too little info.

Comment: What about my question 2 `[recorder record]` does not resume recording but it starts to record it as a new file.

Comment: I can't give you more info because i didn't work with recorder too close + too low info here is. I suggest it can be problem in some your code. Maybe you lose record position or recreate recorder somewhere. Try to debug all methods. Maybe you will catch something interesting, what will answer to your question.

Comment: I already checked `recorder` instance is same throughout recording `i.e` before going to background and after coming to foreground.